# Kernel Parameters not applying in REFInd

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, refind

For some reason, setting kernel parameters are completely ignored in my refind.conf. Here is the relevant config:

```
menuentry "Arch Linux" {
    volume   "Arch Linux"
    loader   /boot/vmlinuz-linux-zen
    initrd   /boot/initramfs-linux-zen.img
    options  "root=PARTUUID=e63233fa-99a1-48ed-892a-6a5d1ad59c9b rw text initrd=boot\intel-ucode.img biosdevname=1 ipv6.disable=1"
    submenuentry "Boot using fallback initramfs" {
        initrd /boot/initramfs-linux-zen-fallback.img
    }
    submenuentry "Boot to terminal" {
        add_options "systemd.unit=multi-user.target"
    }
}
```

I have the biosdevname=1 and ipv6.disable=1 kernel parameters, which are supposed to change network interface names and disable ipv6 respectfully, but it does neither. I know the refind.conf entry is being recognized, because changing the "icon" menu for the below entry works, just not for any kernel parameters. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if placing `biosdevname=1 ipv6.disable=1` before `initrd=boot\intel-ucode.img` instead helps.

Answer (score 0):

Refind passes kernel parameters. I checked that in dmesg,

```
Kernel command line: root=PARTUUID=90ca582a-f687-41e5-b351-21ebaebd86ad rw mitigations=off clocksource=tsc tsc=reliable initrd=\boot\initrd.img-5.11.0-49-generic
```

[In the todo list on refind](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/todo.html), I see this line under bugs:
"If you have a manual boot stanza for a Linux kernel with both an initrd line and a second initrd file specified on the options line, both initrd files will be passed to the kernel in most situations..."

Based on this try removing one of the two initrd entries in your menuentry.

Comment: Do you have the link to the bug report? Please [edit] and add it to you answer.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to examine the CURRENT kernel options is:
$ cat /proc/cmdline
although the recent 'dmesg' is adequate.

The problem *seems* to be the syntax.
"ipv6.disable=1" seems to not be correct syntax in any recent kernel.  There are some similar 'sysmctl' arguments that might belong in a /etc/sysctl.conf file.

"biosdevname=1" requires some userland tools including a /usr/lib/udev/... file, and a binary, '/usr/sbin/biosdevname' or similar.  You may need to re-install the kernel to enact these changes.